# virtual environment requirements.txt

Tags: virtualenv, requirements.txt

I would like to put a requirements.txt file in my virtual environment. The two ways I have thought about  are making a txt file and then moving it to the correct directory (I do not know how to find the directory: when I type workon, the PathToScripts and PathToSitePackages says C:\Users\A.virtualenvs...) and making a requirements.txt file once I am in the directory (I know not how to make a file while in the correct directory). Are any of my ideas a good way to go about solving this problem? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal thing to do is to put the requirements.txt file in the the root of your application source code. This way you can place it under version control with the rest of your application artifacts. That's what virtualenvwrapper expects you to do. It's why virtualenvwrapper distinguishes between the directories where the virtual environments are created and the working directory you specify when creating one. I understand why you might want to put requirements.txt in with the virtual environment, but it's not the usual way.

There might be a way to specify that the virtual environment directory be the same as the working directory. You could try specifying that the working directory be the same as where the virtual environment gets built when you create it, our again you could edit the file after the fact. But it's not really the way people usually do things.

You'll have to look in the docs for the directory where the vms are created for the os you're using. Under Linux they get get put into a hidden directory in your home.